# undefined local variable or method `apipie' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007f90819df738>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am building the documentation of the API of a project.
After installing the gem 'apipie' in my project with the command `rails g apipie:install`, I got the following changes in my files:

```
create  config/initializers/apipie.rb
 route  apipie
```

It added `apipie` to my routes, so I got this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `apipie' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007f90819df738>
```

Any idea on how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I followed the pattern of this commit:

https://github.com/RohitRox/eventbook/commit/0206372edcddec39515b4a58b0e07ec20fa62e8b

It helped me solve it